# How do I catch ConfigurationParsingException?

Tags: java, exception, jvm, dropwizard

How do I catch `io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException` so I can log it properly?

Somehow it bypasses all catch blocks

```
public class App extends Application<AppConfig> {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);


  @Override
  public void run(final AppConfig config, final Environment environment) {
    try {
      environment.jersey().register(new StatusResource());
      LOG.info("start-up");
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      LOG.error("start-up failed: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      new App().run(args);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      LOG.error("failed to create foo: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Posting the stack trace may help.

Comment: @Slaw there is no stack trace, that's the problem

Comment: What if you run it through a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of DropWizard, none of the methods that you are calling throw any exceptions.  I would venture to say that one of the methods you call is handling the error being thrown, so it is not propagating upwards to your catch blocks.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Added after a comment:**
Where the exceptions are caught?

[`at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/1a49d4aa8dadd99c500998d30ac7b6b07f359b3d/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/cli/Cli.java#L77-L84) gives us the answer.

What could be done to achieve the goal:

From the [release notes which are a long read](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/about/release-notes.html#v1-3-0-mar-14-2018) there is this [PR №2260](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/2260). This seems to be dealing with the stated problem: logging in JSON format during the bootstrap phase before the configuration is applied.

This could be useful or not depending on how `dropwizard`'s logs are configured and transported to the ELK stack. If a local log file is used, then the StdErr and StdOut should be redirected to this file. Then `LogStash` should be able to deal with them. If some direct network transport is used - I don't know.

**Second edit:**
There is also the [`check` command](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/cli/CheckCommand.java). It's used for validation of the configuration settings. So it could be integrated somewhere in the deployment toolchain for verification of to be deployed configuration.

```
~/source/dropwizard-static$  java -jar target/dropwizard-static-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar check config1.yml
config1.yml has an error:
  * Unrecognized field at: loging
    Did you mean?:
      - logging
      - assets
      - server
      - metrics
      - httpClient
        [1 more]

~/source/dropwizard-static$  java -jar target/dropwizard-static-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
usage: java -jar dropwizard-static-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [-h] [-v] {server,check} ...

positional arguments:
  {server,check}         available commands

named arguments:
  -h, --help             show this help message and exit
  -v, --version          show the application version and exit
```

**Original answer following:**

I have a toy `dropwizard` project [here](https://gitlab.com/zloster/dropwizard-static). When I try to start it with broken configuration:

```
#logging:
loging:
  level: INFO
#  level: DEBUG
  loggers:
    com.gitlab.zloster: DEBUG
```

I get the following:

```
~/source/dropwizard-static$  java -jar target/dropwizard-static-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config1.yml
io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: config1.yml has an error:
  * Unrecognized field at: loging
Did you mean?:
  - logging
  - assets
  - server
  - metrics
  - httpClient
    [1 more]

at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException$Builder.build(ConfigurationParsingException.java:279)
at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:140)
at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:89)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:126)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:74)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
at com.gitlab.zloster.ServeStaticApplication.main(ServeStaticApplication.java:21)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "loging" (class com.gitlab.zloster.ServeStaticApplicationConfiguration), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "assets", "viewRendererConfiguration", "logging", "httpClient", "server", "metrics"])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.gitlab.zloster.ServeStaticApplicationConfiguration["loging"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822)     
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserialize(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:155)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3984)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2276)
 at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:127)
 ... 6 more
```

It seems to me that the exception is logged properly*.
*This of course is depending on the definition of "logged properly".

You could check how it works following the classes in the first stacktrace (before `Caused by:`). If you don't see an exception logged this means you have to check your logging configuration and if the standard IO streams are redirected to somewhere.

Comment: The logs need to be properly formatted JSON and sent to our ELK stack so we can view them in Kibana. Otherwise they will just sit on an EC2 instance somewhere in the cloud and no one can see them or even know they exist. For every exception I need to call `LOG.error("Exception", e);` to make all this happen.

Comment: Please, edit your question to reflect these important details. I'll update the answer.